# Unable to get ipython reload Modules

Tags: python, ipython, anaconda, python-import

I am struggling to let ipython reload the modules.

I have tried:

- `%load_ext autoreload
  %autoreload 2`
- edit ipython_config.py and add
  `c.InteractiveShellApp.extensions = ['autoreload']` 
  `c.InteractiveShellApp.exec_lines = ['%autoreload 2']`
- load modules with `%aimport mod_name`

I am testing this in a setting where I first import a class, then add a class variable, and finally run a method using this new variable.

> EDIT:
>   To explain what goes wrong. When trying to use this new variable, it is not found (AttributeError Exception). I have to import the class again, and then it works. It is really annoying to do this manually.

**Specs**
I am using ipython notebook 4.1.0 and Python 2.7.11 |Anaconda 2.5.0 (64-bit)|.

Suggestions on what might be erroneous will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about what it's doing or not doing? It's not clear what is going wrong.